# Python 'else' Statement - Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I'm brand new to Python and have been trying to set up a little display for my Murmur server.

I'm trying to complete the following but fail to figure out what's the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
usersnotauth=0
users=server.getUsers()
for key in users.keys():
  if (users[key].userid == -1):
    usersnotauth+=1

if users > 0:

    lcd.set_cursor_position(0, 0)
    backlight.rgb(255,255,255)
    lcd.write("Online Users: %1" % users

else:

    lcd.set_cursor_position(0, 0)
    lcd.write("No Online Users")
    backlight.rgb(0,0,0)
```

Error:

```
File "MurmurDisplay.py", line 81
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis here

```
lcd.write("Online Users: %1" % users)
                                    ^
```